# MessageBox appearance in Windows Server 2003 and Windows7

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

we are working on Delphi 7. Recently we have moved from Windows Server to windows 7. we are handling all the error messages in our application through MessageBox. MessageBox appearance is different in Windows Server 2003 and windows 7. Please find below screen shots, which shows difference in windows server 2003 and windows 7.

[image: MessageBox Windows Server 2003 and Windows 7]

we want windows 7 message box to display same like windows server.

Comment: Normally you would want your app to keep the OS look and feel. Is there a reason you want your app to use old-style dialogs, not the new Windows 7 style ones? Functionally they are the same, and all other apps on a Win7 system will use the new ones so normally yours should too.

Answer (score 4):

The `MessageBox` API is implemented by the system. It is a dialog implemented by Win32 in the user32 module. So you are just picking up the standard Windows dialogs. If you try to replicate the old XP/2003 dialogs on Windows 7, your application will look out of place.

Now, if you are absolutely desperate to replicate the XP/2003 appearance, then you cannot do that through `MessageBox`. You would need to create your own dialog. Create a form. Add a `TImage` for the icon, a label for the text, and whatever buttons you need. Show the form with `ShowModal`. Indeed, the `Dialogs` unit has a function that creates just such a form, `CreateMessageDialog`.

```
var
  MessageBoxForm: TForm;
....
MessageBoxForm := CreateMessageDialog('Your message goes here', mtError, [mbOK]);
Try
  MessageBoxForm.ShowModal;
Finally
  MessageBoxForm.Free;
End;
```

And there's even a simple wrapper that allows this one-liner:

```
MessageDlg('Your message goes here', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
```

That is how to do what you ask but I cannot endorse that as being a good idea. Times change, and it is usually best to move with the times.

Comment: if same appearance is not possible then MessageDlg is a good option. I will find a way to generalize it. Thanks.

Comment: The latter use TaskDialogIndirect by default, you have to un-set UseLatestCommonDialogs or disable themes.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Not in Delphi 7, which is what the asker is using

Comment: Ok, missed that one. I wouldn't suggest using it either, for the additional reason of being a form owned by application. For error reporting, going with the bare minimum is better.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Agreed. I think MessageBox and accept the platform native appearance is usually the best option.

Comment: @DelphiLearner Might I ask why you don't want to accept the platform default appearance?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Client want to have the same appearance as Winserver 2003.

Comment: Windows 95 are 20 years old. It would be about time that people drop its look and feel from Windows apps. If nothing else dropping XPManifest component on main (or any other) form would be step in right direction. Next mandatory thing to learn would be how [Windows manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) work.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I suspect that the asker agrees, but that the client is of a different mindset.

Comment: I can see... maybe adding additional fee for mimicking old look might change clients POV.